# Http Redirect to Https in latest chrome version

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, http, iis, https

I have some videos hosted on my server and a third-party application using those hosted videos in their web application. I am using the IIS server and provide the URL to access those videos which they(third party) used on their web page as a video source.

The problem is the link I provide them is using HTTP protocol but their application is using HTTPS protocol before chrome update it is working fine. Since the update to Chrome version 80 when they click on the play button the requested link is converted automatically from HTTP to HTTPS and didn't play the video.

To explain it more they have a webpage and on that page, they are using video tag and as a source to that video tag, they are using my hosted video links that use HTTP.

I saw the update about same-site in cookies in new chrome 80 but didn't understand does it needs to be done on my site or the other party.

So my questions are should I change my protocol to HTTPS?
Can I add a cookie through IIS (I know something about URL-Rewrite but don't exactly know what to do)?
Did I need to add a cookie through IIS?

Hopefully I am able to explain it properly. Sorry in advance if it is still ambiguous.

Thanks for help

Comment: "the link I provide them is using HTTP protocol but their application is using HTTPS protocol" is a red flag. Mixing HTTP/HTTPS has been problematic for decades, so no surprise that latest Chrome no longer allows that. The whole world is moving to full HTTPS, so enabling HTTPS access to your resources is probably the right way to go.

Comment: It sounds like the application has been added into HSTS. Have you tried to remove the domain from chrome://net-internals/#hsts? Chrome keep promoting full https for security reason. So if the method doesn't work, you may have to replace http with https. URL rewrite shouldn't be able to fix this.

Comment: @JokiesDing well i tried that but it didn't work and even if it works I can't ask all the users to do that to use our resources.

Comment: @LexLi Yes you are right Mix Content is kind of blocked by the latest chrome and it redirects requests to HTTPS automatically. So I end up enabling HTTPS for my resources. Thank you.